# How do I position cursor in terminal using a command?

Tags: macos, terminal, position, alias, text-cursor

I'm on a mac running lion. What I really want is a shortcut for `git grep -n "..."`

My current solution is `alias gg='git grep -n'` which works (kinda).

What I think would be ideal is something where I can type `gg *enter*` and the result would be `git grep -n "*cursor here*"` . I know that control-b will move the cursor back one if that sheds any light on this matter?

Or perhaps where I can type `gg thing to search` and it will perform a `git grep -n "thing to search"`

I know I'm being picky but I don't know too much about how unix commands work and this seems like a good learning experience.

Comment: I use autohotkey in Linux for this kind of thing. Something similar is probably available for osx.

Comment: Without knowing your shell, the only general solution is something supported by system-wide tools (such as input methods) or the terminal program itself.  For example, you can find tools that let you create multiple clipboards and paste arbitrary strings into any application's text fields.  If you want something defined in the shell such as a parameterized alias, the method varies by shell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is `bash` (which I think has been the default on OS X for a long time), you can replace your alias with a shell function:

```
gg () { git grep -n "$@" }
```

When you type `gg thing to search`, the function will run `git grep -n`, adding all the parameters you gave to `gg` in place of `"$@"`.